# What is the status of web mining?

Tags: mining-pools

Now that I have my pool up and running, how long before we get a production web Miner?  I'm trying to get non-techies start mining and a great start would be a web Miner.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There's no official web miner for Monero. Some developers wrote code for that purpose but that has nothing to do with the Monero project itself.

There are services where one may register, paste code to their website, and make visitors mine for them (and for miner authors, as they charge quite high fees).

Regardless of the origin of the code, this way of mining is highly inefficient. The mining algorithm is designed to run as machine code on bare CPU/GPU chips, not as high-level language in virtualized environment of a browser. Of course, WebAssembly optimizations may drive the overhead lower but don't expect it to be profitable unless you have **HUGE** traffic on your website.

And when you deal with huge traffic, the last thing you want is to scare people off by running some shady code on their computers, which spins up fans, eats batteries and usually generates anti-virus warnings. Having many visitors, you'll certainly find a better way to monetize that traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "production" but there's an open source JavaScript based  web miner for Monero, Electroneum and Bytecoin called CrytoNoter that can be found [here](https://github.com/cryptonoter/CryptoNoter). However, most browsers and antiviruses are starting to block these now due to bad press.

Comment: What I mean is an actively updating source code.  I setup the CryptoNoter but there hasn't been any activity from the dev for a few months.

Comment: @AndrewAdmire Why would it need updating if it works?

Comment: It doesn't work, there are many issues but the dev has not replied.  I would like to see the web miner be able to do 2 things.  1) Have a list of groups on one page, "click here to support group A, click here to support group B" 2) Integrate it into a web splash/portal page.  You go to a "public" wifi and you need to keep the mining page open in order to browse the internet.